# Converting To Floating Point

Tags: c#, floating-point, modbus, bitconverter, ushort

I have two ushort integer. 
Integers : 2206,41247

I want to convert to float this integers. For this;

```
void Main()
{
    GetSingle(2206,41247).Dump();
}
public static float GetSingle(ushort highOrderValue, ushort lowOrderValue)
{
    return BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(lowOrderValue).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(highOrderValue)).ToArray(), 0);
}
```

I coded something in Linqpad. This functions result is **9,547158E-34**

But in **Modbus Poll** program converts **0** this integers.

I reading this integers from remote device with Modbus Protocol. And correct value is **0**

My question; How the Modbus Poll program converts this integers to float ? How can value be zero ?

Any idea ?

Comment: There is no way that the bytes from those two integers would represent 0 if they were bytes from a float. A zero float is composed of bytes that are all 0. E.g. try `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", BitConverter.GetBytes((float)0)));`

Comment: Yes you are right. All binary must be zero in floating number for zero. But how can this happen ? In Modbus Poll converts this integers to zero.

Comment: It's very very small, I'd guess modbus must be rounding. If mod bus is showing to 5, even 30 decimal places this will show as zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I arrived at the same number. Remember that 9,547158E-34 is *really tiny* - maybe it is just cast to an int afterwards, yeilding 0?